# Payment method buttons sometimes work sometimes no

Tags: magento-2.1, php, javascript

I need a little help, sometimes the buttons of the method payment doesn't work, I can't find what is going on, in the most of the cases they work.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Magento Stack. Can you please share more information like which magento version you are using? and In which scenario its not working. Thanks

Comment: Hi i´m using magento 2.1, i select all the products and add to the cart, when the process is in the methood payment i have 4 buttons with the payment options, but one of the buttons sometimes work and sometimes not, in the most of cases work. thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

When I find that elements on Magento 2 don't work, that's usually an issue with JavaScript. It may not be loading properly, or at all.

What I usually do is login via SSH then run these commands:
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

If that doesn't work, flush your browser cache or use a different one. It's also possible that large processing delays in Magento itself cause the JS not to completely load so checking for any bottlenecks is another step to take.

If you're using a CDN for your site, flush that as well.

Comment: thanks for answer Marisa, i´m going to try out your suggestions.